# prevent escaping of | pipe in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, escaping, uri

After searching this site and several others, I did not find anything that was similar (forgive me if I missed something).  I am using VS Basic 2010 and I am posting to a site that requires a "|" (pipe) in the actual URL.  My initial string has the "|" in a couple of places, but when I create the URI it translates the "|" into "%7C".  I have attempted several options but with no success...see below:

```
dim urlstring as string = "http://abcd.com/!A=Something&B=nothing|now=this|later=that"
dim myUri as Uri = New Uri(Uri.UnescapeDataString(urlstring),UriKind:=UriKind.Absolute)
myUri.GetComponents(UriComponents.PathAndQuery,UriFormat.Unescaped)
```

Based on several other similar issues, I attempted to modify the configuration file by adding...

```
idn enabled="All"
iriParsing enabled="true"
```

But that didn't prevent the escaping either.

Any suggestions would be appreciated...Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Chr(124)

```
"http://abcd.com/!A=Something&B=nothing" & Chr(124) & "now=this" & Chr(124) & "later=that"
```

Comment: Hi Josh - Yes, I tried the Chr(124) option as well and that was also translated to %7C.  I'm thinking that I may have to create my own URI class and bypass or override the "iswellformed..." method (if that's the item being tripped to cause the translation).